# Mapping through objects and render in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a React Native project where i am getting object like the attached image. I need to map through them and render description and rate from them.

[image]

How can i acheive this. I have been trying with `Object.keys` but not been able to do it. Here's what i have tried. Don't know if it makes sense:

```js
{Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key, index) {
    return (
       <Text>
         {myObject.map((rate, description) => {
            return (
              rate,
              description
              )
         })
       </Text>
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have tried first.

Comment: Updated it. But i'm messing up in the second maping i guess. @basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to map the rate and description, you don't need the second `map` -- you can just use the key to get the entry from the original object and then access its properties directly:

```
{Object.keys(myObject).map(key => {
        const item = myObject[key];
        return (<View>
          <Text>{item.rate}</Text>
          <Text>{item.description}</Text>
        </View>
      )})}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not use map on objects so try with bellow code

```
       <>
          {Object.keys(myObject).map((key, index)=>  
          <Text>{myObject[key].description}, {myObject[key].rate}</Text>
             )
          }
       </>
```